# Add unique css class to first iteration of foreach php loop

Tags: php

Beginner's question. I have a working foreach loop using bootstrap for styling and tab navigation. I need to declare the class of ONLY the first tab (iteration) as "active" as in class="nav-item active".

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach($content['tabs'] as $tab){ echo 
       '<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
           <button class="nav-link" id="pills-'.$tab["label"].'-tab" 
           data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-'.$tab["label"].'" 
           type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-'.$tab["label"].'" 
            aria-selected="true">
           <h2 class="h4">'.$tab["label"].'</h2>
           </button>
        </li>';
     } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a variable to have a value of 1 and increment it with each iteration of the foreach loop. Once you have that you can check if the current iteration is equal to 1.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
<?php $i = 1; foreach($content['tabs'] as $tab){ echo 
   '<li class="nav-item ' . ($i == 1 ? "active" : "") . '" role="presentation">
       <button class="nav-link" id="pills-'.$tab["label"].'-tab" 
       data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-'.$tab["label"].'" 
       type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-'.$tab["label"].'" 
        aria-selected="true">
       <h2 class="h4">'.$tab["label"].'</h2>
       </button>
    </li>';
$i++; 
} ?>
```

Comment: Or just replace `$i++` with `$i=0`